# Select specific value in multiple dimensions via linq expression in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem with a linq expression in C#.

I have an info class which contains an array

```
public fruits[] fruits { get; set; }
```

This fruits class contains another set of data:

```
public anotherSet[] anotherSet { get; set; }
```

And this class in turn has an `id`.

```
public string id { get; set; }
```

Now I want to perform a match of my variable with the `id` via a linq expression. Note, of course, that this involves multiple dimensions. 
There can be multiple **fruits** and multiple **anotherSet**.

I want and alignment like the following:

```
fruits.anotherset.id == myVariable
```

the fruit basket is a KeyValuePair with <key, info> 
This info object then contains the fruits[].

But something like this doesn't work:

```
var filteredId = myFruitsBasket.Where(x => x.Value.fruits.Where(x => x.anotherSet.Where(x => x.id == myFruitsId)));
```

**I don't want to filter by the myFruitBasket, but need the array of fruits[].**

Comment: The result of a lambda expression passed into linq where should be a boolean. consider switching to [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0) inside your where expression.

Comment: `myFruitsBasket.Where(x => x.Value.fruits.Any(x => x.anotherSet.Any(x => x.id == myFruitsId)))` should fix the errors you are getting right now, not sure it will yield the correct results though :)

Comment: this should be posted as an answer @JochemVanHespen

Comment: Yes post it as an answer. think that was my mistake in thinking

Comment: Done boys! thanks for pointing that out

Comment: And how can i filter after the fruits[]? now i would choose a separate one from the different fruitbaskets. but i need the fruits[]... I would edit the question with this condition.

Comment: so the result of your linq expression should be fruit[] instead of fruitbasket[]?

Comment: Yes exactly sir :)

Comment: `myFruitsBasket.Where(x => x.Value.fruits.Any(x => x.anotherSet.Any(x => x.id == myFruitsId))).SelectMany(x => x.Value.fruits)`

Comment: perfect thank you. add this to your answer and i will accept it :)

Comment: @41726c adjusted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of a lambda expression passed into linq where should be a boolean. consider switching to [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0) inside your where expression.

`myFruitsBasket.Where(x => x.Value.fruits.Any(x => x.anotherSet.Any(x => x.id == myFruitsId))).SelectMany(x => x.Value.fruits)` should fix the errors you are getting right now, not sure it will yield the correct results though :)